# PDO query returns nothing with PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have this PHP code:

```
    <?php
    if (!extension_loaded('PDO')) {
        dl("pdo." . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);
    }

    if (!extension_loaded('pdo_sqlite')) {
        dl("pdo_sqlite." . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);
    }

    function ejecutar_sqlite($consulta, $bbdd) {
        $dsn = "sqlite:$bbdd";
        echo $dsn . "\n";
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn);
            $resultado=$dbh->query($consulta);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
        if(empty($resultado)) echo "EMPTY!!! \n";
        return $resultado;
    }

    $filas = ejecutar_sqlite('select * from test', '/home/sqlite/bbdd/testbbdd')
    foreach($filas as $f){
        echo $f[id] . "|" . $f[name];
    }

    ?>
```

Besides, I have two differents versions of PHP (5.1.6 and 5.2.9) installed on differents folders of the server (long story...).

My problem is that, when I run this code on the 5.1.6 version, the PDO query returns nothing, but when I execute it over the 5.2.9 version, it works fine. I need to fix this, because I can't use the 5.2.9 version for running it.

PDO and pdo_sqlite modules are already installed and added to "php.ini" (it doesn't show any error or exception while creating the PDO object or running the query, it just doesn't return the expected values from the query).

Any idea of where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. For today there are some problems in PHP v =>5.1.6 with PDO. For Example:

If you’re running PHP 5.1.6 and just started using PDO for your database connection, it’s likely you’ll run into quite an annoying bug.
Lets test a simple query partly taken from PHP documentation.

```
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $myPDO->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->rowCount() >= 1) {
    // iterate through results
}
```

Everything seems great. The problem is that $sth->rowCount() will always return 0. No matter how many results your query returns, the value of rowCount() will always be 0.

The solution is  create our own simple PDO and PDOStatement classes.
**class myPDO extends PDO {**
//your code

Hope, it will help

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking more about a configuration problem... I'll check if I can upgrade to a newer version, and if I don't, I'll try with your solution (or maybe I'll try with Python :p )